# Что внутри функции lerp

Tags: c#, unity3d

в Unity 3d  есть метод `Vector3.Lerp`

Принимает 2 вектора и разницу по времени между кадрами, дельта тайм.

На выходе вектор, напоминает что-то среднее по расстоянию, но не совсем, кто знает что там внутри происходит?

Comment: [Данная функция получает промежуточное значение (интерполирует) между векторами a и b на основе t.
При t равное 0 (или меньше) вернёт a. При t равное 1 (или больше) вернёт b. При t равное 0.5 вернёт среднее значение между a и b.](https://poqxert.ru/blog/unity/tutorials/matematika/matematika-unity-urok-13-vector-interpolyaczii)

Comment: Какая-то сложная математика

Comment: @Alex78191 ничего сложного, разность векторов скалярно умноженная на время. Вектор разности определяет направление движения, а скалярное произведение корректирует пройденное в этом направление расстояние с учетом времени. Графикой, увы, не получится заниматься без минимального понимания векторных операций.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
public static Vector3 Lerp(Vector3 a, Vector3 b, float t)
    {
        t = Mathf.Clamp01(t);
        return new Vector3(a.x + (b.x - a.x) * t, a.y + (b.y - a.y) * t, a.z + (b.z - a.z) * t);}
```

Вот что конкретно находится в Vector3.Lerp